# Case statement in shell - problem

Tags: shell, unix

I'm completely new to shell and I'm trying to include a case where the function's arg #1 is greater or equal 12 then it should return 1. But the below doesn't work.

```
case $1 in
     -ge 12)        NUM=1   ;;
     *)         NUM=0   ;;
esac
echo $NUM
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to use `case` for some reason? If not, `if` seems more natural:

```
if [[ $1 -ge 12 ]]; then
  NUM=1
else
  NUM=0
fi

echo $NUM
```

With `case`, bash performs arithmetic expansion on both *word* and *pattern*, so you could write

```
case 1 in
  $(( $1 >= 12 )) )  NUM=1 ;;
  $(( $1 >=  7 )) )  NUM=2 ;;
  *)                 NUM=0 ;;
esac
```

Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Yeah, because I'll be adding a lot more conditions and case makes it look cleaner. So you're saying it's not possible with CASE?

Comment: Updated. I'm not sure if the extra syntactic noise produces a cleaner result, but I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

The case statement does not interpret operators like -ge.  From the bash man page:

```
   case word in [ [(] pattern [ | pattern ] ... ) list ;; ] ... esac
          A case command first expands word, and tries to match it 
          against each pattern in  turn,  using the same matching rules as 
          for pathname expansion (see Pathname Expansion below).
```

You should use a conditional expression in an `if` statement.

Comment: Keep reading: "Each *pattern* examined is expanded using tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic substitution, command substitution, and process substitution."

Comment: arithmetic substitution is not the same as evaluation of conditional expressions.  There's nothing implying that -ge is supported here.

Answer (score 0):

Case needs to take a pattern expression, e.g. a string.

I either recommend using a simple if statement:

```
if [[ $1 -ge 12 ]]; then
  NUM=1
else
  NUM=0
fi
```

Or express the branches in pattern expressions:

```
case "$1" in
     [0-9])             NUM=1   ;;
     1[0-2])            NUM=1   ;;
     *)                 NUM=0   ;;
echo $NUM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case "$1" in
     [0-9]|1[01])NUM=0   ;;
     *) NUM=1   ;;
echo $NUM
```

Comment: What about >99? What about 30, 31, 40, 41...?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the program `/usr/bin/test`:

```
if test "$1" -ge 12; then NUM=1; else NUM=2; fi
```

Comment: there's no need to use external test..!!

Comment: Care to explain why not? Using `test` is portable and it is more Unixy, i.e. to have tools that do one thing well and not have the shell be able do everything, unless you are talking about Perl :p